# This function takes 2 arguments but 1 argument was supplied

Tags: rust

I have an error

```
this function takes 2 arguments but 1 argument was supplied (solution.rs)
   |
   |         if let Some((i, j)) = Self::find_key(key) {
   |                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ --- supplied 1 argument
   |                               |
   |                               expected 2 arguments
```

How can I fix the error?

My code:

```
struct MyHashMap {
    m_data: Vec<Vec<(i32, i32)>>,
    m_size: usize
}

impl MyHashMap {

    fn new() -> Self {
        let n: usize = 1000;
       return  MyHashMap{
           m_data: vec![vec![]; n],
           m_size: n
        }
    }

    fn hash(n: i32) -> usize {
        return n as usize % 1000;
    }

    fn find_key(&self, key: i32) -> Option<(usize, usize)> {
        let hash_key = Self::hash(key);
        let bucket = &mut self.m_data[hash_key];
        if bucket.len() > 0 {
            for i in 0..bucket.len() {
                if bucket[i].0 == key {
                    return Some((hash_key, i));
                }
            }
        }
        return None;
    }
    
    fn put(&self, key: i32, value: i32) {
        if let Some((i, j)) = Self::find_key(key) { // ERROR IN THIS LINE
            self.m_data[i][j].1 = value;
        } 
    }
    // some code
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need `self.find_key(key)`, not `Self::find_key(key)`.

The former calls the `find_key` method on `self`, implicitly providing `self` as its first parameter. The latter tries to call it as an associated function, which means no implicit `self` parameter is passed, and so it expects you to provide both arguments explicitly.

For reference: [Associated functions & Methods](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/fn/methods.html)

Answer (score 2):

`find_key` expects two arguments, so in principle you have to call it with three.

```
Self::find_key(self, key)
```

However, since the first argument is declared to be a `self` argument, you can call it with dot notation instead.

```
self.find_key(key)
```

Specifically, `Self::find_key` is the function itself, as a two-argument function with no special behavior. `self.find_key(...)` is syntax sugar which inserts `self` as the first argument (and determines, at compile-time, which namespace to look for the function in using the type of `self`).

Unlike Java and some other languages, Rust will *never* automatically insert `self`. If you want to call a method on the "current" object, you have to write `self.` explicitly. There's no "instance variable scope" like there is for `this` in Java.